# PHP strange characters on transalation

Tags: php, utf-8, msgfmt

I have a application made in PHP, on this application I have the option to translate the page with some languages, but if I try to translate to Spanish the characters with accent marks, shows a question mark symbol (�) like: acci�n.

To generate the transalation files, i'm using the following command:

```
msgfmt messages.po -o messages.mo
```

On my file .po, with the following structure from top to bottom:

```
msgid "Yes"
msgstr "Si"
```

On twig:

```
{% trans "Yes" %}
```

My mysql is set to UTF-8(but in this case I'm not using info from the database) , all my .php files are set with UTF-8 encoding, my html pages too. I don't why this happen? Could it be nginx configuration?

Comment: What if you try this at the top of your PHP file: `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`

Comment: What are the headers (first msgstr) and encoding of your PO file? Probably not UTF-8.

Comment: my .po header already contains: "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n"

Comment: @heliosk your .po file encoding should be utf-8, but also your PHP file should contain `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');` (in case your webserver isn't  sending that HTTP header already).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)